# I am getting error after run this program, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript

```
var nums = [45, 35, 25, 15, 1, 25, 35,];
var dup;
    for(var i = 0; i<nums.length; i++){
    for(var j = nums[i+1]; j<nums.length; j++){
    if(nums[i] == nums[j]) {
    dup.push(nums[i]);
    alert(dup);
    }
    }
}
```

Please help me in this program, when I am running this program I am getting this error. I am trying to push duplicate value in dup variable.
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: You simply did not initialize the variable.

Comment: Please explain in a code.

Comment: Thank you, it's working, but cannot get the right value

Comment: Oh, and the second loop should be `for (j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++)` I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var nums = [45, 35, 25, 15, 1, 25, 35,];
var dup = []; // Initialize this array

for(var i = 0; i<nums.length; i++) {
  for(var j = i+1; j<nums.length; j++) { // Change this line
    if(nums[i] == nums[j]) {
      dup.push(nums[i]);
      alert(dup);
    }
  }
}
```